# How to close browser activity when returning to calling activity?

Tags: android, twitter, android-activity

I have this situation. I have an Activity A that sends an intent to create an Activity B which is a browser to authenticate a user with his twitter account. When credentials are submitted the control goes back again to Activity A and I can keep navigating through the app. However, if the users leaves the app, the browser activity is being resumed, forcing the user to close the browser.

The problem is that I would like to remove the browser activity from the stack once I get the authentication credentials.

Do you know if this is possible? I cannot use startActivityForResult since the authentication needs to be made in the browser, I don't have any control over that activity. Thanks a lot

EDIT:

I'm starting the activity like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)).setFlags(Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could put something in OnResume() in Activity B which checks if this is the first activation of Activity B, and closes it automatically if it isn't?

Update: You could alternatively use an AsyncTask to post the credential info to the website, using a DefaultHttpClient and HttpPost. Unfortunately I've only used HttpGet in this scenario, but there is some code [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) that may be of use.

Comment: Hi Dan, unfortunately I don't have any control over Activity B (android Browser). So I'm only to take any actions after or before calling Activity B. Is there a way to get access to the activities stack on android?

Comment: Sorry - didn't pick up that you were using the actual browser. I guess an alternative would be to do the browsing / authentication in your Activity A as another thread rather than using a browser application. I've done similar using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) as an inner class.

Comment: Did you use by any chance a WebView?, do you have an example at hand?

Comment: Uhm got it. However, I think I might not be able to take that approach since the user needs to get to the webpage (twitter) to put the credentials. I think I could ask for credentials and post the data to the webpage; but I think that's not an option in this particular case. Thanks anyway, I resolved the situation using a custom activity that displays a WebView.